# Random Integer Producing Unexpected Values

Tags: c#

I am trying to use this piece of code to pick out two random locations in a multidimensional array, I was getting errors saying that the values were outside the bounds of the array so I decided to write them to console to see what it was returning. below is my code and beneath that is a log of the console.

Coming back to edit this question I should explain what I failed to do in the comments. I was clearly very tired and was under the impression that somehow, my pseudorandom numbers were returning letters sometimes. in reality what was happening was that I was writing out the two random positions (which were from -1 to the size of the array -1 which explains the values being outside of the array) and every two values I printed I waited for a `Console.ReadKey();` this is what caused the "random" letters every 2 values, it was the buttons that I was pressing on the keyboard in order to see the next two numbers.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfMines;)
    {
        int pos1 = rand.Next(boardSize)-1;
        int pos2 = rand.Next(boardSize)-1;
        Console.WriteLine(pos1);
        Console.WriteLine(pos2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

board size is equal to int 5.

Console Log:

```
2
0
d1
0
d0
-1
d-1
3
d2
3
d1
-1
d-1
1
d2
3
d-1
3
d3
2
```

Comment: `for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfMines;)` you never increment counter

Comment: 0 is a valid value. If you subtract 1 from it you get -1. Not sure why you'd need the -1 anyway, the upper bound is exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a board size of 5 then calling just `random.Next(boardsize)` is fine

[the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_) says that the number passed into Next is exclusive. This means if you pass 5 in you'll get a number between 0 and 4 back. If your board is implemented as a 5x5 array then it will have rows and columns that are indexed from 0 to 4

If you ever use the `Next(lower, upper)` method on Random, be aware that lower bound is inclusive, so `Next(1,5)` returns a random number between 1 and 4

You could probably do away with your boardSize variable as the arrays that hold the mines have a `.Length` that could be passed to Next. It would also mean you can run rectangular boards..

Comment: because of something that i want to implement later in the program the board is actually a 7x7 but i want to limit the places where it it creates values to the inner 5x5 square

Comment: Oh, in that case follow the latter advice, and use `random.Next(1, boardsize-1)` - you want to "generate a random number between 1 and 5" for a board size of 7 (an array that runs from 0 to 6). This means you do your +1 and -1 to come in from the board edges when you call random rather than generating a random number between 0 and 6 and subbing one off it (-1 to 5; the 5 is correct, the -1 is not)

Comment: And implement PaulBaxter's advisory to increment the counter otherwise you'll just fill the whole board with mines

Answer (score -2):

turns out it was just a problem of the values going into the negatives due to a number in the wrong spot, the d's were coming from the `Console.ReadKey();` where i forgot to put true into the brackets.

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. Can you please try to reword as a set of clear sentences?

Comment: so the reason for the first error was because one of my variables was off by 1 causing it to generate -1 to 4 instead of 0 to 5, this is what caused the first error, in my attempt to troubleshoot the error i wrote the values to the console, this resulted in the code looping too fast to read so i put a Console.ReadKey() in the code which because i didn't set the Console.ReadKey() to Console.ReadKey(true) the keys i were pressing were appearing in the console causing me to believe that i was somehow getting d's in my value when in reality it was just the key i was pressing to see the next values

Comment: Please work out how to end sentences. Then please edit your answer so that it clearly articulates why it is an answer to the question.

Comment: sorry for the terrible question and answer, i was very tired at the time. I have edited a section of the question to explain what was going thorough my head.